# MongoError in filter with $elementMatch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using [**Mongoose**](http://mongoosejs.com/) in my [**NodeJS**](https://nodejs.org/en/) backend for a chat.

I want to filter all the messages from conversation that the user don't read it in my [**MongoDB**](https://www.mongodb.org/) db:

**controller**

```
 var filter = {
             $and:[
                   {
                     conversation:req.conversation.id
                   },
                   {
                     $not: 
                     {
                       readers:
                       {
                         $elemMatch:
                         { 
                          user:req.user.id
                         }
                       }
                     }
                  }
                 ]
               };

Message
    .find(filter)
    .exec(function(err,messages){
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            console.log(messages);
            res.jsonp(true);
        }
    });
```

### Debugging this code:

- `messages`-> `undefined`
- `err`-> `Error {name: 'MongoError'}`

And the filter variable:

[image: debugging filter variable]

I don't understand the error, I think maybe I applied wrong the filter... **What is incorrect in my code?**

Thank you so much!! I share the Message shema below:

**message shema**

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
conversation:{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Conversation'
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
user:{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
message:{
    type: String,
    default:''
},
readers:[{
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user:{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}]
});
```

Comment: Considering your "actual query needed" is as simple as `{ "conversation": req.conversation.id, "readers.user": { "$ne": req.user.id } }` then I fail to see the point in debugging anything. Neither `$and` nor `$elemMatch` are required here as 1. All MongoDB query arguments are already "AND" arguments, and 2. `$elemMatch` is supurflous when you only want a "single" property anyway. Just use the query structure you should be using. Any other errors that result are because your "inputs" are not what you expect or also simply do not match the data.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution work's well!!!

Comment: Best advice. Loose your overterse SQL declarative thinking. This is "functional programming" and it is meant to be "simple". ie `"A" equals "B" AND "C" equals "D"` is essentially `{ "A": "B", "C": "D" }` as a nice and simple organic data structure.

Comment: Thanks! If you want to write the solution that you propose above, I will mark to gd solution :)